# Epsilon Delta Proof of Limit

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : (−\infty,0) → \mathbb{R}$ be the function given by $f(x) = \frac{x}{|x|}$. Use the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of a $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = -1.$

Workings:

Informal Thinking:
We want $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

$\left|\frac{x}{|x|} - -1\right| < \epsilon$

$\left|\frac{x}{|x|} + 1 \right| < \epsilon$

$\left|\frac{x + |x|}{|x|} \right| < \epsilon$

$x + |x| < |x|\epsilon$

$|x| < |x| \epsilon - x$

Take $\delta = |x|\epsilon - x$

Proof:

Suppose $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta = |x|\epsilon - x$

So $0 < |x| < \delta = |x| \epsilon - x$

I'm wondering if what I did so far is correct and what I should do next. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $\delta$ needs to be independent of $x$; you cannot define $\delta$ the way you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are approaching $x$ from the left, that means $x<0$. As such, we have $|x| = -x$. So, when you get to your third line we have $$\left|\frac{x + |x|}{|x|} \right|=\left|\frac{x + (-x)}{|x|} \right| = 0 < \varepsilon$$ The inequality clearly holds for all $x<0$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$. Can you find a $\delta$ now?

Comment: I could take $\delta$ = $\epsilon$

Comment: @MrTambourineMan Yup, that should work.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You went astray when you dropped the absolute value bars. Instead, remember that we are only considering $x<0,$ so what is $|x|$?

Also, as graydad points out, your $\delta$ is only allowed to depend on the choice of $\epsilon,$ not on $x$.

Comment: When $x < 0 = |x| = |-x| = x$

Comment: @MrTambourineMan so if $x=-2$ then $|x|=-2$?

Comment: @MrTambourineMan: I think you may be confused. You might want to check [your definition](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/207735/28900) of the absolute value function.

Answer (score 0):

Take some $\epsilon >0$. We need to schow there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\forall x: 0>x>-\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-(-1)| <\epsilon$. 
Hint: If $x<0$ what does it say about $f(x)$ what is $|f(x)+1|$ in this case?